Unhandled error during execution of component update when click vue3 simpletypehead
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') this error was showing when i click the vue3 simple typeheaad
how to fix this error
when i click the input field in vue3 simpletypehead i have a uncaught typeerror  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')
